# How do I delete lines of 1st file if it matches the string present in the 2nd file in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, sed

Consider I have two text files.

First File name - "Emails.txt" with the following data:

```
00iiiiiiii_l@hotmail.com
00rrrrrrrr@hotmail.com
00zzzzz@gmail.com
00eeeeee@gotmail.com
00gggggg@uor.edu
00uuuuuuuu@yahoo.com
00e21_ss@cmail.com
00gggggggg@cmail.com
00zzzzzzzz48@hotmail.com
00aaaaaaa_2020@gotmail.com
jjjjjjjj@gmail.com
```

Second text file - "Banned.txt" with the following strings:

```
@gotmail.com
@cmail.com
@uor.edu
```

How to delete all the lines in the 1st text file "Emails.txt" if it matches the stings of any line present in the second text file "Banned.txt"?

The desired output of the new file should be:

```
00iiiiiiii_l@hotmail.com
00rrrrrrrr@hotmail.com
00zzzzz@gmail.com
00uuuuuuuu@yahoo.com
00zzzzzzzz48@hotmail.com
jjjjjjjj@gmail.com
```

Can this be done using SED or awk in Linux? Can you please suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep -v` is enough. The flag `-f` allows you to do exactly what you want:

```
grep -vf Banned.txt Emails.txt
```

If you want to do something more complicated out of the list of banned addresses, e.g. impose that they match the whole of the domain, you'll need to generate a regex from your `Banned` file:

```
cat Banned.txt | tr "\n" "|" | sed -e 's,|,$\\|,g' | sed -e 's,\\|$,,'
```

gives the desired

```
@gotmail.com$\|@cmail.com$\|@uor.edu$
```

Then:

```
cat Banned.txt | tr "\n" "|" | sed -e 's,|,$\\\\|,g' | sed -e 's,\\|$,,' | xargs -i grep -v '{}' Emails.txt
```

(doubling the number of escapes `\` as they're being evaluated when going through `xargs`). This will match and remove `me@uor.edu` but not e.g. `me@uor.education.gov`.

Comment: This is not correct. The Output of the file should show ONLY the line whose sting doesn't match with Banned.txt file. Which means, all the domains / strings listed in the Banned.txt file should get deleted in the first file Emails.txt

Comment: That's the purpose of the `-v`. Have you tried it?

Comment: grep -vf worked like a charm... Thanks.

Comment: After some more research, I found - Rather using a long regex, this works with this simple line too: `grep -vf <(sed 's/$/$/' Banned.txt) Emails.txt`

Comment: @JoneyWalker Indeed that's shorter!