# How do I delete lines of 1st file if it ONLY EXACT Matche of the string present in the 2nd file in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, sed

Consider I have two text files.

First File name - "Emails.txt" with the following data:

```
sale@gmail.com
info@yahoo.com
all@gmail.com
help@domain.com
abcdsale@gmail.com
abcd.info@yahoo.com
```

Second text file - "Roles.txt" with the following strings:

```
sale@
info@
all@
help@
```

How to delete all the lines in the 1st text file "Emails.txt" if it matches ONLY EXACT stings of any line present in the second text file "Role.txt"?

The desired output of the new file should be:

```
abcdsale@gmail.com
abcd.info@yahoo.com
```

I tried using

```
grep -vf Role.txt Emails.txt
```

But, this command also deletes the line if it matches all the characters of the Role.txt.

I want to remove only it matches EXACT as per Role.txt file, and swip everything if there are other characters before the desired string.

[Here](https://superuser.com/a/1397442/988683) someone gave a similar solution for removing line matching EXACT string at the end of each lines, but in this I need the regrex to so the same at the beginning of each lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second file should look like this:

```
^sale@
^info@
^all@
^help@
```

because `^` matches the beginning of a line.

You can rebuild the file with `sed -i 's/^/^/' Role.txt`. To be clear: this will change the file. Then your original command

```
grep -vf Role.txt Emails.txt
```

will work.

---

Alternatively, with your *original* `Role.txt`, in a shell that supports process substitution (e.g. Bash):

```
grep -vf <(sed 's/^/^/' Role.txt) Emails.txt
```

In this case `sed` adds `^` characters on the fly and `Role.txt` remains unchanged.

Comment: Perfect! This works great. :)

Comment: So if I want to do the same at the end of file, will this work if i add ^ at the end of line too? eg: @domail.co^ such that @domain.co.uk will be skipped? or should we substitute the end with $?

Comment: @JoneyWalker No, you probably want `$`. Please research [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended).

Comment: Ok got it... This works: grep -vf <(sed 's/$/$/' Test2.txt) Text1.txt